# LibGDX input only runs my loop once and not continuously when the mouse is just clicked

Tags: java, android, libgdx, mouseclick-event

```
public void update(float delta){
    position.x = getX();
    if(Gdx.input.justTouched()){
        for(;position.x < 864; position.x = position.x + 0.5f){
            setX(getX() + 3f*delta);
        }
    }       
}
```

The above code shows the loop that makes a block move which is like the character from one side of the screen to the other and stop when it reaches the x coordinate of 864. The loop runs fine when it's on it's own but it runs as soon as I compile the game. What I want it to do is to run the loop when the mouse is clicked anywhere on the screen. But what actually happens is that it runs the loop only once and I have to click the mouse multiple times before the loop is complete and the block is on the other side of the screen (images below). Can someone please shed some light on how I would go about setting it up so that it runs the whole loop and moves the block from left to right with a single mouse click.

Thanks a lot.

Images:
This is where the block starts at: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5CDU.png
This is what I want it to end up like when the mouse is clicked: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnZA1.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use loops like this in `update` because they will block the render loop. The render loop already provides the loop, so you just need to increment it on each call to update. Keep a boolean to decide whether your movement needs to start. Something like this:

```
boolean hasBeenTapped = false;

public void update(float delta){

    if (Gdx.input.justTouched())
        hasBeenTapped = true;

    if (hasBeenTapped && getX() < 864)
        setX(getX() + 3f*delta);

}
```

If you want to use [scene2d](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d), then it has its own actions system that handles this stuff for you, possibly more intuitively than this. I personally use scene2d only for UI stuff though, because I find it too time consuming/restrictive to set up the game code with.

Comment: Thanks a lotttt, I do have one more small problem however, the block ends past the x value of 864 so it's partly off screen, it seems the faster I make it move the more off screen the block becomes. Any ideas?

Comment: Just add a line to constrain it. `if (getX()>864) setX(864);`

Comment: Thank you again, sorry for being so incompetent but how would you go about making the block move back again after you click it once more? Thank you

Comment: That's fairly involved, because now you're talking about the block having different states, and behaving differently in each state. Can you create a new question for it?

Comment: Ah right, I'm really new to coding so I have no clue. I'm trying to learn as I go. I'll make a new question for it soon, thanks a lot.

Comment: I've set up a new question about the block having different states. Could you have look please?